# How do I use same data in multiple referenced library

Tags: matlab, global-variables, simulink, local-variables

As we now, when the model grows, we start working with referenced models. They then become "libraries" that could be referenced multiple times.
If the referenced model has some local data, like state or some buffers, each reference has its own data, so for example if you have a buffer manager, every instance that calls the push model uses its own buffer. This of course is not what one need - we need to store the data in same buffer. Using of global data is not possible, cause it is not allowed for multiply referenced models.
Do you have any idea what is the solution here?
Thanks in advance

PS: What I missed to say(maybe because of the keyword simulink that I have assign) is that my question is related to Simulink. Thanks again

Comment: I added the clarification that it's about simulink, so the terms are from there

Comment: Ah, OK, I don’t know much about Simulink.

Comment: Simulink models can reference the base workspace variables using the `FromWorkspace` block, or you can parameterise the blocks with variables, or set the parameters programatically... without a clear [mcve] it's hard to say why that isn't an easy solution, or why the use of libraries complicates anything.

Comment: There is an example of how to use data store blocks to do this here: [Using Data Stores Across Multiple Models](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/using-data-stores-across-multiple-models.html)

Comment: Ok then, I made a very simple example. A model main that calls two instances of the reference model ref. I don't know how to attach it here, so: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ix6gx44z4ac1ivm/Sample.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. If one defines the global data externally(in a .c file) then he could possibly make routines that get and set the data. Afterwards, they could be called from matlab function from the events.